# mongo inside ansible-operator image

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, ansible, dockerfile, operator-sdk

I need the mongo shell installed inside the [ansible-operator](http://quay.io/operator-framework/ansible-operator:v1.0.0) image.

My first attempt was to use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:4.2.9

FROM quay.io/operator-framework/ansible-operator:v1.0.0
COPY --from=0 /usr/bin/mongo /usr/bin/mongo

COPY requirements.yml ${HOME}/requirements.yml
RUN ansible-galaxy collection install -r ${HOME}/requirements.yml \
 && chmod -R ug+rwx ${HOME}/.ansible

COPY watches.yaml ${HOME}/watches.yaml
COPY roles/ ${HOME}/roles/
COPY playbooks/ ${HOME}/playbooks/
```

Unsurprisingly, this didn't worked.

> "stderr_lines": ["/usr/bin/mongo: /lib64/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/mongo)", "Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration Can not set up PEM key file."]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out...

Just add this to your Dockerfile.
([mongodb-org-4.2.repo](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/))

```
USER 0
COPY mongodb-org-4.2.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo
RUN yum -y update \
    && yum install -y mongodb-org-shell \
    && yum clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
RUN rm /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo
USER ${USER_UID}
```